# Vim-Plug uses wrong directory for plugins

Tags: neovim, plugin-system, init

I decided to switch from vim to neovim on a new system. I downloaded nvim, copied my .vimrc to `~/.config/nvim/init.vim` and installed vim-plug to `~/.config/nvim/autoload/`.

At the start of my init.vim I have

```
call plug#begin("~/.config/nvim/plugged")

Plug 'tpope/vim-commentary'
Plug 'tpope/vim-surround'
Plug 'vimwiki/vimwiki'
Plug 'vim-airline/vim-airline'
Plug 'scrooloose/nerdtree', { 'on':  'NERDTreeToggle' }
Plug 'tmhedberg/SimpylFold'
Plug 'sirver/ultisnips'
Plug 'easymotion/vim-easymotion'
Plug 'yegappan/taglist'

call plug#end()
```

I sourced the file and used `:PlugInstall`.
For some reason this is the output vim-plug gave me:

```
Updated. Elapsed time: 0.103060 sec.
[xxxxxxxxx]

- Finishing ... Done!
x SimpylFold:
    warning: unable to access '/home/udalny/.config/git/config': Is a directory
    warning: unable to access '/home/udalny/.config/git/config': Is a directory
    fatal: unknown error occurred while reading the configuration files
x vimwiki:
    warning: unable to access '/home/udalny/.config/git/config': Is a directory
    warning: unable to access '/home/udalny/.config/git/config': Is a directory
    fatal: unknown error occurred while reading the configuration files
x ultisnips:
    warning: unable to access '/home/udalny/.config/git/config': Is a directory
    warning: unable to access '/home/udalny/.config/git/config': Is a directory
    fatal: unknown error occurred while reading the configuration files
x vim-airline:
    warning: unable to access '/home/udalny/.config/git/config': Is a directory
    warning: unable to access '/home/udalny/.config/git/config': Is a directory
    fatal: unknown error occurred while reading the configuration files
x vim-commentary:
    warning: unable to access '/home/udalny/.config/git/config': Is a directory
    warning: unable to access '/home/udalny/.config/git/config': Is a directory
    fatal: unknown error occurred while reading the configuration files
x vim-surround:
    warning: unable to access '/home/udalny/.config/git/config': Is a directory
    warning: unable to access '/home/udalny/.config/git/config': Is a directory
    fatal: unknown error occurred while reading the configuration files
x vim-easymotion:
    warning: unable to access '/home/udalny/.config/git/config': Is a directory
    warning: unable to access '/home/udalny/.config/git/config': Is a directory
    fatal: unknown error occurred while reading the configuration files
x nerdtree:
    warning: unable to access '/home/udalny/.config/git/config': Is a directory
    warning: unable to access '/home/udalny/.config/git/config': Is a directory
    fatal: unknown error occurred while reading the configuration files
x taglist:
    warning: unable to access '/home/udalny/.config/git/config': Is a directory
    warning: unable to access '/home/udalny/.config/git/config': Is a directory
    fatal: unknown error occurred while reading the configuration files
```

I tried changing the argument of plug#begin to `~/test` (i mkdir-ed it preliminary) sourced the file and run `:PlugInstall` again. I got the same output.

Comment: Looks like you have a directory `git/config` in your `~/.config` directory so when vim-plug tries to git clone a plugin (i.e. download the plugin) it see this git config in the path, tries to use it and fails because this is not a file but a directory. Depending on what is in this `git/config` you should try to  move it or rename it so that it doesn't mess with git repos in your config directory.

Comment: That sucks, git expects ```$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/config``` for its config file.

Comment: @Udalny, yeah, but it seems your `~/.config/git/config` is a *directory* and not a file! It seems that is the problem... I imagine you'll see the same issue if you try to just use `git` in the command-line directly... Try removing that directory? I imagine that will get it to work then...

Comment: Also... Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: @Udalny it's great to hear that you solved your problem. What you are encouraged to do on this site is to post an answer to your own question and to mark it as accepted with the green mark button next to your answer: That avoid polluting the question title with "[SOLVED]" and that give other users a consistent way to know it a question has an answer. I'm editing your question to remove what you added in the title and I'll let you post and accept your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comments; the problem was that I had `~/.config/git/config` as a directory, not as a file.

To fix it, I made it a regular file and copied the contents of `~/.config/git/config/.gitconfig`.